# Что значит код?

Tags: python

```
[int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

Answer (score 7):

Этот код превращает строку, введённую пользователем, в список с числом/числами `int` (разделяются пробелом на вводе).

Например, возьмём этот код, результат присвоим переменной `result` и выведем с помощью `print`:

```py
result = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
print(result)
```

Ввод: 12345
Вывод: `[12345]`

И ещё пару примеров с пробелами:

Ввод: 12 34 5
Вывод: `[12, 34, 5]`

Ввод: 1 2 3 4 5
Вывод: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Такие конструкции называются ["генератор списка"/"списковое включение"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) или [List comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension).

Comment: Вводить нужно через пробел, а вывод список целых 1 2 3 4 5 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Стоит сказать, что эта конструкция называется генератор списка (List Comprehension)

Comment: Или более распространенное название — списковое включение.